# Como achar o menor valor de uma matriz em lua?

Tags: lua, lógica, lua-table

Eu fiz esse código que faz uma Matriz (Pelo menos eu acho que está fazendo) e depois escreve todos os valores nela. obs: Os valores são aleatórios.
Preciso encontrar o menor valor da matriz, mas a lógica que usei sempre me dá um resultado previsível.

**Exemplo:** Digamos que o range do invertalo é dado por *x* e *y*. Sendo *x* o menor valor que pode ser assumido e *y* o maior.(No código x=0 e y=2500).No código, o valor da variavel menor está sempre dando *x* + 2, ou seja, no meu código a variavel *menor* está sempre resultando no valor 2. Se eu definir o menor valor do range como 5, por exemplo, no final o valor da *variável* menor será 7.(x=5, x+2 = 7)

```
matriz={}
for l=1,20 do
    matriz[l]={}
    for c=1,40 do
        matriz[l][c] = math.random(0,2500)
    end
end
menor = matriz[1][1]--Inicia na menor posição possivel
for i=1,20 do
    for j=1,40 do
        print("O valor na Linha:"..i.." Coluna:"..j.." é "..matriz[i][j])
        if matriz[i][j]<menor then-- essa parte deveria encontrar o meno valor
            menor = matriz[i][j]
        end--Final
    end
end
print("O menor valor encontrado é:"..menor)
```

Esse é o código que fiz, como estou começando, não estou entendendo onde está o erro dele.

Comment: ao bater o olho no código notei essa linha `menor = matriz[1][1]`, inicie sua variável `menor` com um número infinito ou que seja maior do que o range dos número randômicos inseridos

Comment: Eu iniciei a variável menor com o valor acima do range dos números randômicos e o problema persistiu.

Comment: `Se o intervalo dos números sorteados é 0 e 5, no final a variável Menor irá conter o valor 0 + 2, ou seja 2.` ??? não entendi ....

Comment: Eu dei uma melhorada no exemplo. Curto e grosso: O valor da variável menor é sempre o valor minimo do range mais 2.

Comment: humm isso é um problema do lua em algumas plataformas, as vezes ele gera sempre as mesmas sequencia, antes do `math.random` insira `math.randomseed(os.time())`

Comment: Agora que notei que ele realmente está gerando os mesmo valores sempre. No caso o problema está na plataforma, correto?(Minha preocupação é saber se a lógica está errada)
obs: Estou usando o Scite pra compilar.
Eu não entendi a parte de inserir o randomseed antes, poderia ser um pouco mais específico?

Comment: a lógica esta correta, não esqueça de sempre iniciar sua variável menor  conforme indicado no meu primeiro comentário ...

Answer (score 1):

Como sugerido pelo @ederwander, faltou colocar um comando para preparar a geração de números pseudo-aleatórios. Fora isso sua lógica está correta.

```
#!/bin/lua

math.randomseed(os.time()) -- faltava isso

matriz = {}

for l=1,20 do
    matriz[l] = {}
    for c = 1,40 do
        matriz[l][c] = math.random(0,2500)
    end
end

menor = matriz[1][1] -- Inicia na menor posição possivel

for i = 1,20 do
    for j = 1,40 do
        print("O valor na Linha:"..i.." Coluna:"..j.." é "..matriz[i][j])
        if matriz[i][j] < menor then -- essa parte deveria encontrar o meno valor
           menor = matriz[i][j]
        end -- Final
    end
end

print("O menor valor encontrado é:" .. menor)
```